# why shouldn't I use a push-mark

Tags: emacs, elisp

I implemented a small function, which parses an SQL INSERT statement and highlights a column value when a cursor is on a column name and vice versa.

Then I wanted to add a possibility to quickly jump between column name and column value. I used push-mark in my implementation, so I can jump with C-x C-x (exchange-point-and-mark). It works too, the only thing which bothers me is a elisp doc, which says

> Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often
>   try to use the mark for the wrong
>   purposes.  The mark saves a location
>   for the user's convenience. Most
>   editing commands should not alter the
>   mark.

My usage of mark - is it correct? Or what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider an analogy with the position of point: the user only wants point to move when they issue a point-moving command. It would be exceedingly annoying if random operations like font-locking moved the point. Hence the recommendation to wrap function bodies in `(save-excursion ...)`.

If your function sets the mark *explicitly* for the user, that's fine. (In this case I suggest calling your function something like `sql-mark-column-value` to make it clear that setting the mark is one of the things it does.) The point of the documentation you quoted is that commands should not set the mark *incidentally* as a result of doing something else.

If your function just happens to set the mark when the user places point on a a column name in a SQL statement, that's probably not so convenient. Imagine a use case of someone trying to cut or copy a section of a SQL statement; every time they try to move point within the statement their mark gets clobbered! For this use case you probably want to provide a separate command like `sql-goto-column-value` instead of relying on `exchange-point-and-mark`.

Of course, if this is purely for your own use, anything goes.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is the correct use of push-mark. I think the documentation discourages the use of push-mark instead of save-excursion for the purpose of saving the state of the buffer while performing certain operations.

Comment: FWIW, the documentation's intention is to make the programmer write (let ((foo
(point))) ... (goto-char foo)) instead of the something like
(set-mark) ... (exchange-point-and-mark).